# Sign conventions of work without parametrization

Tags: work, conventions

It is not my homework or anything like that... I just confused about it.
When calculating the work a force does when pushing a mas along the x-axis according to the formula $W_{b a}=\int_a^b f(x) d x$
For example, we have a force $\vec{F}(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2} \hat{x}$ (The size $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and the direction is -$\hat{x}$)

For the work from a to b $W_{b a}$
$$\begin{aligned}
& \vec{F}=\frac{-1}{x^2} \hat{x}, d \vec{x}=d x \cdot \hat{x}, a \leq x \leq b \\
& W_{b a}=\int_a^b \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{r}=\int_a^b-\frac{1}{r^2} d r=\left.\left[\frac{1}{r}\right]\right|_a ^b=\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a}
\end{aligned}$$

For the work from b to a $W_{a b}$,
we start the integral at b and finish at a, so now dx is in opposite direction hence negative.

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \vec{F}=-\frac{1}{x^2} \hat{x}, d \vec{x}=-d x \cdot \hat{x}, b \geq x \geq a \\
& W_{a b}=\int_b^a \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{r}=\int_b^a \frac{1}{r^2} d r=\left.\left[-\frac{1}{r}\right]\right|_b ^a=\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a}=W_{b a}
\end{aligned}
$$

In my calculation I have that $W_{b a}=W_{a b}$

when I’m using parametrization, I don’t have mistake.
let’s calculate the work from point a to point b with parametrization.
First, the road from a to b is $$\begin{aligned}
& x(t)=((b-a) t+a) \hat{x}, t \in[0,1] \rightarrow \frac{d \vec{x}}{d t}=(b-a) \hat{x}, \vec{f}(x(t))=\frac{-1}{((b-a) t+a)^2} \hat{x}, \\
& W_{b a}=\int_a^b \vec{f}(x) \cdot d \vec{x} \underset{\substack{x(0)=a, x(1)=b}}{\equiv} \int_0^1 \vec{f}(x(t)) \cdot \frac{d \vec{x}}{d t} d t=\int_0^1 \frac{-1}{((b-a) t+a)^2}(b-a) \underbrace{\hat{x} \cdot \hat{x}}_1 d t \\
& =-\left.(b-a)\left[\frac{-1}{(b-a)((b-a) t+a)}\right]\right|_0 ^1=\left.\left[\frac{1}{((b-a) t+a)}\right]\right|_0 ^1=\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a}<0
\end{aligned}$$

And now the road from b to a -
$$\begin{aligned}
& x(t)=((a-b) t+b) \hat{x}, t \in[0,1] \rightarrow \frac{d \vec{x}}{d t}=(a-b) \hat{x}, \vec{f}(x(t))=\frac{-1}{((a-b) t+b)^2} \hat{x}, \\
& W_{a b}=\int_b^a \vec{f}(x) \cdot d \vec{x} \underset{\substack{x(0)=b, x(1)=a}}{=} \int_0^1 \vec{f}(x(t)) \cdot \frac{d x}{d t} d t=\int_0^1 \frac{-1}{((a-b) t+b)^2}(a-b) d t= \\
& =-\left.(a-b)\left[\frac{-1}{(a-b)((a-b) t+b)}\right]\right|_0 ^1=\left.\left[\frac{1}{((a-b) t+b)}\right]\right|_0 ^1=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}>0
\end{aligned}$$

As expected $W_{b a}=-W_{a b}$

Comment: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now dx is in opposite direction hence negative

Here is your mistake. Your $x$ coordinate still increases in the same direction so $dx$ points in that direction. Changing the limits of integration does not change the direction in which the coordinate increases.

Comment: the coordinate "decrease" in the direction of the road from point B to point A, which is a negative direction. The parametrization I have used shows that in the case of this road, the particle goes in negative direction as time increases $$x(t)=((a-b) t+b) \hat{x}, t \in[0,1] \rightarrow \frac{d \vec{x}}{d t}=\underbrace{(a-b)}_{<0} \hat{x}$$

What I wonder is how it is easy to see it with the time variable but not without it

Comment: @YardenSharabi it is only hard to see if you do it wrong. It is wrong to change dx to negative just because you change the limits of integration.